# How to completely remove a keyboard layout from windows

Tags: windows, windows-registry, keyboard-layout, group-policy, acl

I have a software that, when run, automatically adds a specific keyboard layout

Is there any way to prevent this?

some sort of lock on windows' keyboard layout list?
or some sort of permission restriction on the app?
or just delete that bloody keyboard layout from `C:\Windows\` if it's a seperate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

1- Find the identifier for your keyboard layout from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values).

2- Open registry editor: `regedit.msc`

3- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts`

3- Delete that keyboard layout's folder. (make a backup if you think you might need it later)